How to create SSL certificate for localhost?
For development purposes, I installed xampp.
I did run C:\xampp\apache\makecert.bat to create a ssl certificate.
Because it is only used on localhost, I did enter "localhost" for
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []: localhost
But now the browser says: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
I assume this is because localhost is not a FQDN?
How can I solve the problem?

It's normal that a self signed certificate is considered not secure.You need to import the certificate in operating system or browser certificate store.

Yes, I did import  the certificate into operating system, as Window suggested into "Trusted Root Certification Authorities tab". But it did not help.
Bowser store would not help. The problem is with the php function getimagesize, which does not open an https link to an image file because of the problem with the cert.

The link is on localhost? So you use curl to retrieve the image?

Yes, the link is on localhost. This is an CMS which uses smarty to output an image, and smarty uses getimagesize() for some calculations. curl is not involved.

Can you post the code, please?

The relevant code is:
$image_src = catFilesOperations::srcImageSpec($pagecontent->Alias(), 2);
$fi = getimagesize($image_src);
The first line returns a link to the file.
Because the code runs fine on production server, I did not wanted to change it only because of the problem with the dev machine. I thought it would be easier to get php accepting the certificate.

Try a var_dump($image_src) and see what came up

$image_src contains the link to the file like "https ://localhost/path/image.jpg" (I had to add the space after https here)

So if it's on localhost why don't you use normal internal path?

Because this code is in the CMS and I prefer not to change it.

Then try add your localhost certificate in the OS trusted certificate store as I told in the main answer.
